# how to perform count for a secod foreign key in django?

Tags: python, django, count, django-queryset

i have three models Category,Post,Comment

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    COLOR_CHOICES = (
        ('primary', 'Blue'),
        ('success', 'Green'),
        ('info', 'Sky Blue'),
        ('warning', 'Yellow'),
        ('danger', 'Red')
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    visited = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    color = models.CharField(
            max_length=20, default='primary', choices=COLOR_CHOICES)

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (True, 'Visible'),
        (False, 'Hidden')
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(
            Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    visited = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Comment(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (True, 'Visible'),
        (False, 'Hidden')
    )
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

I want to perform a query set to get categories and number of comments of each category, I can't find a good way.
I already know how to count posts for each category using annotate.
I tried :

```py
categories = Category.objects.annotate(nb_comments=Count('post__comment'))
```

Comment: And? What's the issue with what you tried?

Comment: What is not working here?

Comment: What you're trying is correct, so that's why we're asking you what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count number of comment that related to specific categoriy:

```
number_of_commemt_for_cat1=Comment.objects.filter(post__category_id=1).count()
```

this query say: count of comment that belong to posts that post are belong to specific category.

and here you can find count of post that related to specific category:

```
number_of_post_for_cat1=Post.objects.filter(category_id=1).count()
```

I'm with mobile so I can't explain enough or put references here for you. hope help.

Comment: i know how to do it for a specific category, but i want to perform this count for all categories